# Advanced select with django ORM

Tags: django, database, django-models, many-to-many, models

I am using the following model:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return "%s (%s)" % (self.name, ", ".join(topping.name
                                                 for topping in self.toppings.all()))
```

And now I want only the elements for vegetarian menu, filtered by tomatoes

```
pizza_item = Pizza.objects.filter(toppings__name='tomatoes')
```

My select is:

```
SELECT `pizza`.`id`, `pizza`.`name` 
FROM `pizza` 
INNER JOIN `pizza_toppings` ON ( 
    `pizza`.`id` = `pizza_toppings`.`pizza_id` ) 
INNER JOIN `web_topping` ON ( 
    `pizza_toppings`.`topping_id` = `topping`.`id` )
WHERE `topping`.`name` = azucar
```

but i want get:

```
SELECT `pizza`.`id`, `pizza`.`name`, `topping`.`name` 
FROM `pizza` 
INNER JOIN `pizza_toppings` ON (
    `pizza`.`id` = `pizza_toppings`.`pizza_id` ) 
INNER JOIN `web_topping` ON ( 
    `pizza_toppings`.`topping_id` = `topping`.`id` ) 
WHERE `topping`.`name` = azucar
```

This last query works fine in mysql db. And works using pizza.objects.raw but i want get using django ORM
Is a select with `topping.name` i try it using `prefetch_select('toppings')`. but i cant get the same select.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values) method for Queryset ?

Something like :

```
pizza_item = Pizza.objects.filter(toppings__name='tomatoes').values("id", "name", "toppings__name")
```

Comment: Could you please describe more your solution?

Comment: This works fine but not return a queryset, only return the values. But the sql code is perfect.

pizza_item = [{'toppings__name': u'tomatoes', 'id': 1L, 'name': u'pizztomato'}]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that's doable. Because when you use **Pizza.objects...** you are limited to the fields that are in the Pizza model. Since the Pizza model does not contain toppings' name field. You cannot retrieve it. You can only retrieve toppings' id field:

```
pizza_item = Pizza.objects.filter(toppings__name='tomatoes').values('id', 'name', 'toppings')
```

Which will provide "toppings"."topping_id" in SELECT.

Also, since you have specified that **toppings__name='tomatoes**, all of toppings' name will be tomatoes in this queryset, so what is the point of having **`topping`.`name`** in your result?

Comment: If i use toppings__name= not is problem, but if i try use toppings__icontains='to' i want get all query.

And want use a queryset and "aggregate" topping.name for get a queryset. if i use valuesqueryset need add all to the query, and cant change easy the model in the future. But thx for all ur help!!

Comment: OK, i see what you mean now. You have to use prefetch_related to get the values from the other model. Pizza.objects.whatever() will not get you the name field of another model.